# Qgis Python - Legends in Horizontal

Tags: pyqgis, legend

I have successfully added legends in Map using Qgis QgsComposerLegend () python programming .(using Qgis python console) but legends are added vertically.I wanted to place legend horizontally.
If you guys have any idea of adding them horizontally,please share with me.

Comment: Did you try to apply the `setColumnCount( int )` method to your legend?

Comment: Don't know how to do it in pyqgis. But in map composer that is done by setting the number of columns at least as big as the number of legend items. So @ArMoraer must be on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but searching through the `QgsComposerLegend Class` i solved it. Try using `setSplitLayer(True)` and `setColumnCount(len(layers))` where 'layers' are equal to `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()`. An example:

```
#... Once composer is created, add a legend as follows
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()
legend = QgsComposerLegend(c)
legend.setTitle("Leyenda:")
legend.model().setLayerSet([layer.id() for layer in layers])
legend.updateLegend()
legendSize = legend.paintAndDetermineSize(None)
# Define xposition and yposition
legend.setItemPosition(xpos, ypos, legendSize.width(), legendSize.height())
legend.setBackgroundColor(QColor("white"))
## this is the part where you set up the horizontal legend
# Set the column count as the number of layers you are working with
legend.setColumnCount(len(layers))
# Set split to true to finish legend horizontal distribution
legend.setSplitLayer(True)
##
legend.setBackgroundEnabled(1)
legend.setFrameOutlineWidth(0.5)
legend.setFrameOutlineColor(QColor("purple"))
legend.setFrameEnabled(1)
c.addComposerLegend(legend)
#...
```

[image]

I'm using QGIS 2.18 Las Palmas.